# find in list of directories saved to a file

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I am using a small Bash script to periodically purge old backups:

```
FILE_LIST=`mktemp --suffix=.list`
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -print0 > $FILE_LIST
xargs --no-run-if-empty --null --arg-file $FILE_LIST rm -rvf
rm -f $FILE_LIST
```

The problem, however, is that files are not guaranteed to be user-writable, so `rm` may fail to delete them. I need therefore to run `chmod` before `rm` in order to change its permissions:

```
xargs --no-run-if-empty --null --arg-file $FILE_LIST chmod -vR 700
```

But this is inefficient, as it calls `chmod` on all the files in the found directories, when the vast majority of them probably don not need to be chmoded. Ideally, I would want to call `find` again, this time with `! -perm -u+w` and searching only in the directories contained in `$FILE_LIST`.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I am basically looking for something to replicate the functionality of `xargs`'s `--arg-file` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it — we can chain `xargs`-`find`-`xargs`-`chmod`:

```
# Find unwritable files and chmod them
xargs -I {} -0r -a $FILE_LIST find {} ! -perm -u+w -print0 | xargs -0r chmod -R 700 -v
```

The full Bash script, thus, would be:

```
FILE_LIST=`mktemp --suffix=.list`
find ~/udit65_backup/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "$PREFIX-*" -type d -mtime +$NDAYS -print0 > $FILE_LIST
# Make unwritable files... writable
xargs -I {} -0r -a $FILE_LIST find {} ! -perm -u+w -print0 | xargs -0r chmod -R 700 -v
xargs -0r -a $FILE_LIST rm -rf -v
rm -f $FILE_LIST
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -writable -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

and then

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -exec chmod u+w {} \; -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I hope this solves the purpose

Comment: You can add `sudo` just before `chmod` if you need. It would be good if sudo is paswdless in that case

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it requires of two executions of `find`, but the files that need to be chmod-ed are a subset of those found with the first run of `find`. That is why I would like to restrict the second search to those files previously found.